# Read the JSON file in the Jersey sources folder

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I have Jersey project `glassfish 2.18` and I am trying to read the JSON file `routes.txt` in this folder scr-main-sources with the Jackson 2.x . How can I get The InputStream of the text document file to get the data from it?

I appreciate any help

**Code:**

```
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("src/main/sources/routes.txt");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Root readValue = mapper.readValue(fileReader, Root.class);
```

**JSON simple:**

```
[{
   "route": 1,
   "info": {
              "stops": [{
                          "arrival_time": {"mon-fri": ["04:24","05:10","05:40"],
                                       "sat": ["05:34","05:55","06:15"],
                                       "son": ["07:00","08:00","05:40"]

                                       },
                          "stops_name": "Tension Way"
                        }],
              "direction": "Surrey Quays"
           }
}]
```

Root class:

```
package org.busTracker.serverSide.json;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"route",
"info"
})
public class Root {

@JsonProperty("route")
private Integer route;
@JsonProperty("info")
private Info info;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The route
*/
@JsonProperty("route")
public Integer getRoute() {
return route;
}

/**
* 
* @param route
* The route
*/
@JsonProperty("route")
public void setRoute(Integer route) {
this.route = route;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The info
*/
@JsonProperty("info")
public Info getInfo() {
return info;
}

/**
* 
* @param info
* The info
*/
@JsonProperty("info")
public void setInfo(Info info) {
this.info = info;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things to consider.

- **Deserializing and format of the JSON.**  Currently your JSON is a JSON array. Unless the class is some type of collection, say a subclass of `List`, the class will map to a JSON object. So you can either remove the `[ ]` from the JSON, or deserialize into a `List<Root>`. For example

  ```
  List<Root> roots = mapper.readValue(is, TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
              .constructCollectionType(List.class, Root.class));
  ```

  Of course if you remove the `[ ]`, then you can deserialize to `Root` instead of `List<Root>`. But maybe you are expecting to have more JSON object in the array (who knows).
- **The format of main JSON object in relation to your `Root` class**.  There seems to be a discrepancy between the format of the JSON and the properties in the class. Here is the format of the class that I see (and would be more inclined to work with):

  ```
  public class Root {

      public int route;
      public Info info;

      public static class Info {

          public String direction;
          public Stops stops;

          public static class Stops {
              @JsonProperty("arrival_time")
              public Map<String, String[]> arrivalTime = new HashMap<>();
              @JsonProperty("stops_name")
              public String stopsName;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- **Accessing the file**. The file should be read from classpath instead of a file on the file system. For that you can use [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), which returns an `InputStream`. So for example, if your file is in `src/main/resources` (Maven structure), then the file would be at the root of the classpath, and you could access it like

  ```
  InputStream is = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.json")
  ```

Here is a complete example with all the points mentioned above

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.json");

        List<Root> roots = mapper.readValue(is, TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
                .constructCollectionType(List.class, Root.class));
        Root root = roots.get(0);

        System.out.println("route: " + root.route);
        Map<String, String[]> arrivalTimes = root.info.stops.arrivalTime;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry: arrivalTimes.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            for (String time: entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println(time);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you tell me how to access arrivalTime when`Stops` is an arra? because it is an array and I forgot to add the box brackets in the simple above.

Comment: Change the class name to `Stop`, just so it makes sense, and chanage the filed in `Info` to `List<Stop> stops`

Answer (score 1):

Read the data from file as a `JAVA` object:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Root readValue = mapper.readValue( new FileReader("src/main/sources/routes.txt"), Root.class);
    Info info = readValue.getInfo();
    System.out.println(info.toString()); //Remove from production code
    Stops stops = info.getStops();
    System.out.println(stops.toString()); //Remove from production code
```

**Other approaches, but not good in your case:**

**Read in a buffer**:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
String s;
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("value are " + s);
}
```

Still if you want to get `File` content as an `InputStream`, then you can go with:

**Prior Java 1.7**:

```
InputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/sources/routes.txt"));

        System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
                + fis.available());

        int content;
        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
            // convert to char and display it
            System.out.print((char) content);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null)
                fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**With Java 1.7 and later:**

```
try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(
                "src/main/sources/routes.txt"))) {
            System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
                    + fis.available());
            int content;
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                // convert to char and display it
                System.out.print((char) content);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is there not need for `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: What you want to do? Do you want to read the data from file or want to map the json from a file to a Java object?

Comment: I have JSONArray like the JSON simple above as `.txt` file in this path  `src/main/sources/routes.txt` and I want to read the file to get the time or any other piece of information from the json file.

Comment: I am  getting these errors `File cannot be resolved to a type
 - FileInputStream cannot be resolved 
  to a type`

Comment: I have created the classes with this link http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  also I have created for this JSON simple 4 classes as the link has generated.

Comment: Then why you want to read content as `InputStream`, I hope you will get the `readValue` populated with data, just extract the information you want out of it. As, `readValue.getInfo()`.

Comment: That was just my solution proposal I thought I have to get the Data in InputStream before starting asking for data. I am still confused. Please can you modified your answer to see how to get data from the root class?